404 error while sending user input to dapr workflow
I have created the workflow with the name TestWF, for user input, The source code is
public class TestWF : Workflow<string, string>
{
public override async Task RunAsync(WorkflowContext context, string input)
{
var message = string.Empty;
try
{
var timeOut = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
context.SetCustomStatus("Waiting for user input.");
var approvalEvent = await context.WaitForExternalEventAsync(
"approval-event",
timeOut);

        if (approvalEvent.IsApproved)
        {
            message = await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(
            nameof(CreateGreetingActivity),
            input);
        }
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        context.SetCustomStatus("Wait for external event is cancelled due to timeout.");
    }

    return message;
}
}

public record ApprovalEvent(bool IsApproved);
I can start it using postman by following the call.
http://localhost:3601/v1.0-alpha1/workflows/dapr/TestWF/start?instanceID=cc44441e-1988-4c61-6297-08dc4ea11006
I started succesffuly but when I try to pass it using the follwoing command, it goes into 404 error.
http://localhost:3601/v1.0-alpha1/workflows/dapr/cc44441e-1988-4c61-6297-08dc4ea11006/raiseEvent/
Any body can help me please?
Regards,
Muhammad Abbas
I am expecting a solution of the error I am facing regarding dapr workflow

Here error lies in send event post call.
http://localhost:3601/v1.0-alpha1/workflows/dapr/TestWF/start?instanceID=cc44441e-1988-4c61-6297-08dc4ea11006
The above line should be changed to as follows.
http://localhost:3601/v1.0-alpha1/workflows/dapr/cc44441e-1988-4c61-6297-08dc4ea11006/raiseEvent/approval-event
you can remove the hyphen in case you get error, in this case the definition workflow event definition will be modified as follows;
var timeOut = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);

context.SetCustomStatus("Waiting for user input.");
var approvalEvent = await context.WaitForExternalEventAsync(
"approvalEvent",
timeOut);
and send event post call will be modified accordingly as follows;
http://localhost:3601/v1.0-alpha1/workflows/dapr/cc44441e-1988-4c61-6297-08dc4ea11006/raiseEvent/approvalEvent
Thanks,
Abbas
